# Need assistance with NSIndexPath

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

in the method below why **indexPath.Row** always return 0???

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
        }

    // Configure the cell.
    [cell.textLabel setText:[mainItems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
    return cell;
}
```

mainItems is a NSMutableArray and has 5 items ("item 1", "item 2",...) the View does get 5 items... but they are all "Item 1" and NOT item 1, item 2...

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that you're returning the wrong value in your implementation of `-numberOfSectionsInTableView`, and the table view is asking you for the 0th row of 5 sections.

Table views have sections, and each section has rows. Many table views only have one section, but many rows in that section. It sounds like you have one section, with 5 rows. Be sure that you return the correct values in each of:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView 
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
```

Comment: tks a lot... indeed i was setting the sections = [mainItens count] and not the items!!! i will mark as correct as soon as possible!